# Typescript/Javascript JEST spyOn not working (with Example)

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I don't know why but my code does not work. Somehow the mock is not working and I get the errors commented on the code.

Any idea what the issue is?

```js
import * as app from './app';

const cars = []; // some car objects

describe('Test', function() {
  it('test1', async() => {

    const spy = jest.spyOn(app, 'method1');
    spy.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(cars));

    const response = await app.main();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // Expected number of calls: >= 1, GOT 0

  });
});

// app.ts

export const method1 = async() => {
  // some stuff
}

export const main = async() => {
  const cars: Car[] = await method1();
  console.log(cars); // undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `method1` needs to be in separate file. If both methods are in the same file then mocking won't work.

So your setup should be like:

- appUtils

```js
export const method1 = async() => {
  // some stuff
}
```

- app

```js
import { method1 } from './appUtils'; 

export const main = async() => {
  const cars: Car[] = await method1();
  console.log(cars); // undefined
}
```

- the test

```js
import { main } from '../app';
import * as appUtils from '../appUtils';

const cars = []; // some car objects

describe('it should work', () => {
  it('should work', async () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(appUtils, 'method1');
    spy.mockResolvedValue(cars);

    await main();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Why ? Original file (app.ts) is working at runtime, it's only fail on jest runner...